# Decoding .webm format doesn't return any BufferedImages

Tags: java, arraylist, decode, javax.imageio, webm

My code here is compiling correctly, but I am running into the problem that my ArrayList of BufferedImages is always empty. Honestly I don't have any knowledge regarding ImageIO or the likes!

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;

import net.sf.javavp8decoder.imageio.WebPImageReader;
import net.sf.javavp8decoder.imageio.WebPImageReaderSpi;

class MyProj{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Main"); 

        ArrayList<BufferedImage> collectedImg=getFrames();
    }

    static ArrayList<BufferedImage> getFrames() throws IIOException{
        File MyWebM= new File("/users/case3/mcclusm4/workspace/LineTech/src/goal.webm");
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        try{
            ImageReader ir = new WebPImageReader(new WebPImageReaderSpi());
            ir.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(MyWebM));


            for(int i = 0; i < ir.getNumImages(true); i++)
                frames.add(ir.read(i));

        }catch(IOException e){}
        return frames;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no exceptions? What value does `ir.getNumImage(true)` return? The code above doesn't work as an MVCE, because we don't have your input file... Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all dont catch `Exception` and do nothing:

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

Now when an exception is catched it silently fails without any information.

Change catch to print stacktrace: `e.printStackTrace()` and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never tested the code in question myself. But...

From looking at the source code of `net.sf.javavp8decoder.imageio.WebPImageReader` it cannot decode `WebM` files. It [only supports single frame](http://sourceforge.net/p/javavp8decoder/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/javavp8decoder/imageio/WebPImageReader.java#l110) `WebP` files.

If you stop swallowing the exception and ignoring it, as suggested by @robocoder, you should get an [`IIOException` with the message `"Bad WEBP signature!"`](http://sourceforge.net/p/javavp8decoder/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/javavp8decoder/imageio/WebPImageReader.java#l184).